# Dr. Java Abstract Animal Class not Compiling - Beginner

Tags: java, inheritance

```
abstract class Animal {

  public abstract void sound();

  public abstract void movement();

}



public class Cat extends Animal{

public void sound(){
   System.out.println("Meows");
}

public void movement(){
System.out.println("Pounces");
}

public static void main(String args[]){

 Animal obj = new Cat();
obj.sound();
}

 Animal obj = new Cat();
obj.movement();
}




public class Dolphin extends Animal{

public void sound(){
System.out.println("Whistles");
}

public void movement(){
 System.out.println("Swims");
}

public static void main(String args[]){

 Animal obj = new Dolphin();
 obj.sound();
 }

 Animal obj = new Dolphin();
 obj.movement();
  }





public class Parrot extends Animal{

public void sound(){
System.out.println("Talks");
}

public void movement(){
System.out.println("Flies");
}

 public static void main(String args[]){

 Animal obj = new Parrot();
 obj.sound();
 }

Animal obj = new Parrot();
obj.movement();
  }
```

It's not compiling? I don't know what's wrong. Sorry I'm a real beginner. I'm supposed to create an abstract animal class with a variable of species and methods sound and movement and three other child classes that inherit from the first one. The child classes must use the sound and movement methods and also have some other methods of their own. Can someone help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you see the duplicate code at the end of what you posted?  Remove it!

Comment: You also can't have two `public` classes within one file that aren't nested.

Comment: I removed the C++ tag since the code is clearly Java.

Comment: You have a duplicate `Dolphin` class and you are calling a method `obj.movement();` in the body of a class, which isn't allowed. Move it inside the class' constructor

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure why you design your source code like that, try something like this.

The abstract class.

```
public abstract class Animal {
    public abstract void sound();
    public abstract void movement();
}
```

The concrete class, I took only Cat class.

```
public class Cat extends Animal{

    public void sound(){
       System.out.println("Meows");
    }

    public void movement(){
        System.out.println("Pounces");
    }
}
```

The main class.

```
public class Main{
   public static void main(String[] args){
       Animal cat = new Cat();
       cat.sound();
       cat.movement();
   }
}
```

Move your main method into another class, don't put it on the concrete class then try compile the Main class.